# How to modify a fixture and intercept a response with the modified fixture

Tags: overriding, cypress, cypress-intercept

I am trying to modify an existing fixture and then override a response with the modified fixture.

I'm able to override the response with predefined fixture or modify the actual response, but I cant do them both at the same time.

For example the actual response can be modified:

```js
 cy.intercept("POST", "response", (req) => {
  req.continue((res) => {
    res.body.result..... = false;
    res.send();
  });
});
```

Also I am using this to override responses using a fixture:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("override", (url: string, fixture: string) => {
  cy.intercept(
    'url',
    fixtureName.json
  );
});
```

I can use cy.readFile() to read the fixture and cy.writeFile() to modify it but I do not want to use this solution.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You are perhaps looking to "merge" response and fixture in some way using the spread operator?

```js
cy.fixture('my-fixture.json').then(fixture => {

  cy.intercept("POST", "response", (req) => {
    req.continue((res) => {
      res.body = {
        ...fixture,              // mostly fixture properties
        result: res.body.result  // except for "result"
      }
      res.send();
    })
  })
})
```

Or

```js
cy.fixture('my-fixture.json').then(fixture => {

  cy.intercept("POST", "response", (req) => {
    req.continue((res) => {
      res.body = {
        ...res.body,             // mostly res properties
        result: fixture.result   // except "result" from fixture
      }
      res.send();
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.fixture()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Accessing-Fixture-Data) to load your fixture file and then follow it with a `.then()` to modify the data and have it as part of your intercept response.

```js
cy.fixture('fruit.json').then((data) => {
  data.fruit = 'Kiwi'
  cy.intercept('GET', '/fruit', fruit).as('getFruit')
})

// test code to trigger request
cy.wait('@getFruit').then(({ request }) => {
  expect(request.body.fruit).to.eq('Kiwi')
})
```